# Print list backwards in Python

Tags: python, list, printing, reverse

I know there are better ways to print things backwards. But for some reason I can't get this to work. Any ideas why?

```
fruit = 'banana'
index = 0
while index < len(fruit):
    print fruit[-(index)]
    index = index + 1
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python

Comment: @gabber, the OP has stated they already know there are other ways to reverse a string, they want to  know why their code is not working

Comment: BTW, the `()` around `index` are redundant, and add clutter to the code.

Answer (score 7):

You reversed everything but the `b`, because you started at 0, and -0 is still 0.

You end up with the indices 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, and thus print `b`, then only `anana` in reverse. But `anana` is a palindrome, so you cannot tell what happened! Had you picked another word it would have been clearer:

```
>>> fruit = 'apple'
>>> index = 0
>>> while index < len(fruit):
...     print fruit[-index]
...     index = index + 1
... 
a
e
l
p
p
```

Note the `a` at the start, then `pple` correctly reversed.

Move the `index = index + 1` *up* a line:

```
index = 0
while index < len(fruit):
    index = index + 1
    print fruit[-index]
```

Now you use the indices -1, -2, -3, -4, -5 and -6 instead:

```
>>> fruit = 'banana'
>>> index = 0
>>> while index < len(fruit):
...     index = index + 1
...     print fruit[-index]
... 
a
n
a
n
a
b
>>> fruit = 'apple'
>>> index = 0
>>> while index < len(fruit):
...     index = index + 1
...     print fruit[-index]
... 
e
l
p
p
a
```

I removed the `(..)` in the expression `-(index)` as it is redundant.

Comment: One of those weird situations where the only reason it's hard to debug is the particular example used. Not many words are a letter followed by an palindrome.